# How is newsletter content chosen?

Tags: support, newsletter

A site's weekly newsletter includes three standard sections: top new questions, greatest hits, and unanswered.  How are the questions for each section chosen?

I can imagine that "top new questions" might be based on hotness, "greatest hits" might be random within a set of questions that meet some unknown-to-me threshold, and "unanswered" might use the same algorithm as the community bump on the main page.  But that's all guess-work, and I know I've seen newsletters sometimes that have left me scratching my head.

I vaguely recall seeing a meta post that explained how the newsletter content is chosen, but I couldn't find it in the [newsletter](/questions/tagged/newsletter) tag here on MSE or by searching.  So maybe it was on a per-site meta, but if so I don't know which.

Comment: That's very bizarre -- that question doesn't appear on the list of questions tagged "newsletter", but it is.

Comment: What do you mean by *that question doesn't appear on the list of questions tagged "newsletter"*? What exact search you tried to perform? In [this simple search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnewsletter%5D+select), it does appear (first result).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I clicked on the tag name, then searched (that is, ctrl-F) the page for (a substring from) the title of that question.  Nada.  There's only one page of results (I have my batch size set to 50 and there are 32 results).  I visually scanned the page too -- ain't there.  I'm going to science this later (browsers incognito, etc) to see if I can characterize it any better.

Comment: Oh fooey, I just spotted it -- for some bizarre reason clicking on the tag takes me to *unanswered* questions on that tag.  WTF?  Ok, fixed now.

Comment: Yeah, the system remembers the last tab you view, for good. If you will go to "featured" tab of a tag, close the browser, open again, choose different tag - you will still be in its featured tab. :)

Comment: I don't remember ever choosing that tab.  I mean, I guess I did at some point, and I browse from the main page not the "questions" link, but... not recent, and totally surprised me.  Thanks.  (I have now put it back to "newest" where it belongs.)

Comment: Yeah, might even just followed a link to that tab, without actually ever clicking it yourself.